# __construct function not constructing correctly in the container symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, containers

Hello all i got a a report-bundle and a service AdminUsersStatsListBlockService that need a UserRepository.php within the report bundle to access function, i tried to add the BookingBundle.php within the report bundle to the construct function but i keep constructing without it here's my code and my errors:

HERE AdminUsersStatsListBlockService.php (so i tried to add the BookingRepository here):

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of the Cocorico package.
 *
 * (c) Cocolabs SAS <contact@cocolabs.io>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace Cocorico\ReportBundle\Block\Service;

use Cocorico\BookingBundle\Entity\Booking;
use Cocorico\ReportBundle\Repository\UserRepository;
use Cocorico\ReportBundle\Repository\BookingRepository; /*(added)*/
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Pool;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BlockContextInterface;
use Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\Service\AbstractBlockService;
use Sonata\BlockBundle\Model\BlockInterface;
use Sonata\CoreBundle\Validator\ErrorElement;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class AdminUsersStatsListBlockService extends AbstractBlockService
{
    protected $userRepository;
    protected $bookingRepository;/*(added)*/
    protected $adminPool;

    /**
     * @param string          $name
     * @param EngineInterface $templating
     * @param UserRepository  $userRepository
     * @param Pool            $adminPool
     * @param BookingRepository  $bookingRepository/*(added)*/
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        EngineInterface $templating,
        UserRepository $userRepository,
        Pool $adminPool = null,
        BookingRepository $bookingRepository/*(added)*/
    ) {
        parent::__construct($name, $templating);

        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
        $this->bookingRepository = $bookingRepository;/*(added)*/
        $this->adminPool = $adminPool;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function execute(BlockContextInterface $blockContext, Response $response = null)
{
        $stat = $blockContext->getSetting('stat');
        switch ($stat) {
            case 'offerers-expiring':
                $results = $this->userRepository->getTopOfferersWithBookingsStatusCount(
                    Booking::STATUS_EXPIRED,
                    null,
                    null,
                    $blockContext->getSetting('limit')
                );
                break;
            case 'offerers-refusing':
                $results = $this->userRepository->getTopOfferersWithBookingsStatusCount(
                    Booking::STATUS_REFUSED,
                    null,
                    null,
                    $blockContext->getSetting('limit')
                );
                break;
            case 'offerers-accepting':
                $results = $this->userRepository->getTopOfferersWithBookingsStatusCount(
                    Booking::STATUS_PAYED,
                    null,
                    null,
                    $blockContext->getSetting('limit')
                );
                break;
            case 'bookings-expired-list':
                $results = $this->bookingRepository->getBookingsExpired(); /*there i want to use it*/
                break;
            default:
                $results = array();
        }

        return $this->renderResponse(
            $blockContext->getTemplate(),
            array(
                'block' => $blockContext->getBlock(),
                'settings' => $blockContext->getSettings(),
                'results' => $results,
                'admin_pool' => $this->adminPool,
            ),
            $response
        );
    }
}
```

Here's the error i get:

> request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: "Type error: Too few arguments to function Cocorico\ReportBundle\Block\Service\AdminUsersStatsListBlockService::__construct(), 4 passed in /var/www/Symfony/var/cache/prod/Container7aqlalh/getCocoricoReport_Admin_Block_Users_StatsListService.php on line 13 and exactly 5 expected" at /var/www/Symfony/vendor/cocorico/report-bundle/Block/Service/AdminUsersStatsListBlockService.php line 40 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Type error: Too few arguments to function Cocorico\ReportBundle\Block\Service\AdminUsersStatsListBlockService::__construct(), 4 passed in /var/www/Symfony/var/cache/prod/Container7aqlalh/getCocoricoReport_Admin_Block_Users_StatsListService.php on line 13 and exactly 5 expected at /var/www/Symfony/vendor/cocorico/report-bundle/Block/Service/AdminUsersStatsListBlockService.php:40)"} []

and the container still not constructing with the BookingRepository:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Argument\RewindableGenerator;

// This file has been auto-generated by the Symfony Dependency Injection Component for internal use.
// Returns the public 'cocorico_report.admin.block.users.stats_list' shared service.

include_once $this->targetDirs[3].'/vendor/sonata-project/block-bundle/src/Block/BlockServiceInterface.php';
include_once $this->targetDirs[3].'/vendor/sonata-project/block-bundle/src/Block/Service/BlockServiceInterface.php';
include_once $this->targetDirs[3].'/vendor/sonata-project/block-bundle/src/Block/Service/AbstractBlockService.php';
include_once $this->targetDirs[3].'/vendor/cocorico/report-bundle/Block/Service/AdminUsersStatsListBlockService.php';

return $this->services['cocorico_report.admin.block.users.stats_list'] = new \Cocorico\ReportBundle\Block\Service\AdminUsersStatsListBlockService('cocorico_report.admin.block.users.stats_list', ${($_ = isset($this->services['templating']) ? $this->services['templating'] : $this->load('getTemplatingService.php')) && false ?: '_'}, ${($_ = isset($this->services['cocorico_report.user.repository']) ? $this->services['cocorico_report.user.repository'] : $this->load('getCocoricoReport_User_RepositoryService.php')) && false ?: '_'}, ${($_ = isset($this->services['sonata.admin.pool']) ? $this->services['sonata.admin.pool'] : $this->getSonata_Admin_PoolService()) && false ?: '_'});
```

Edit: found this, is this the loader ? :

```
services:
    cocorico_report.admin.block.stats:
        class: Cocorico\ReportBundle\Block\Service\AdminStatsBlockService
        arguments:
            - "cocorico_report.admin.block.stats"
            - "@templating"
            - "@cocorico_report.report.manager"
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.block }

    cocorico_report.admin.block.users.stats_list:
        class: Cocorico\ReportBundle\Block\Service\AdminUsersStatsListBlockService
        arguments:
            - "cocorico_report.admin.block.users.stats_list"
            - "@templating"
            - "@cocorico_report.user.repository"
            - "@sonata.admin.pool"
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.block }
```

Thanks in advance for help!:)

Comment: `Pool $adminPool` is optional, but `BookingRepository $bookingRepository` is not. Try switching them around.

Comment: Does your cache need to be cleared in the container? (/var/www/Symfony/var/cache/prod)

Comment: I'll try that thanks @aynber, and Alex Barker i clean the cache everytime yes thanks

Comment: @aynber Where can i see what function is receiving these arguments ?

Comment: Receiving is `AdminUsersStatsListBlockService::__construct()`. Sending, try searching for `grep -R AdminUsersStatsListBlockService *` in your program root. It may just be loaded by the autoloader, in which case no changes are needed. But if you're loading it somewhere else, you may need to fix the arguments.

Comment: Since your service is in a bundle it will not autowire unless you are doing something very strange indeed.  Look for a services file under ReportBundle/Resources and then edit the service definition.

Comment: @notmat do you use git repository, can you show in github.com?

Comment: @aynber edited, cerad edited too, and Imanali the git is private sorry mate

Comment: The loader is only loading in 3 arguments, so while that may be an issue, it's not the issue you're having right now. You're only passing in 4 arguments in BookingRepository, when it should be 5. You'll have to figure out what else needs to be passed in

Comment: Thanks to all its resolved now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So all you need to do is to add the booking repository to the service definition.

```
# ReportBundle/Resources/services.yml
services:
    cocorico_report.admin.block.users.stats_list:
        class: Cocorico\ReportBundle\Block\Service\AdminUsersStatsListBlockService
        arguments:
            - "cocorico_report.admin.block.users.stats_list"
            - "@templating"
            - "@cocorico_report.user.repository"
            - "@sonata.admin.pool"
            - "@cocorico_report.booking.repository" # ADD THIS #
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.block }
```

The assumption here is that you also have the cocorico_report.booking.repository service already defined.  If the repository is something you added then you will have to find the user repository service definition and basically clone it.

There is a lot more information available on how to [explicitly configure services](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#explicitly-configuring-services-and-arguments) .  Just try to avoid confusing it with the autowire approach.